# Please correct this browser Compatibility issue

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

My CSS CODE :

```
body
{
padding:0;
margin:10px auto;
width:800px;
}

.wrapper
{
 width:800px;
 background-color:#0099FF;
}

.bannercont
{
 margin-top:5px;
 height:90px;
 width:800px;
}

.banner
{
 position:relative;
 top:20px;
 background-image:url(../images/livesupport.png);
 width:267px;
 height:32px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>

    <link href="../css/iestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script language="javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="../js/jquery.corners.js"></script>


    <script>

        $(document).ready( function(){
        //$('.banner').corners("30px transparent top");  
        });

    </script>


    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bannercont"><div class="banner"></div></div>


    </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

The banner is displaying centred in firefox and left aligned in Internet Explorer. I need it centered. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some reflections:

- Add a doctype to the page so that it doesn't render in quirks mode.
- Don't set the width of the body element.

Answer (score 2):

add

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

to the banner element

Answer (score 0):

you should use for banner:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

it will get centered browser-wide automatically.